# How to map over array of ImageURLs and display each?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing a multiple image upload. The user should have the possibility to select the images and see a small preview of the selected images. I store the image URL in an array and iterate the url to display the images. The problem is that the image is not updated in the preview. I.e. the first, second, etc. Image is the same (see attached picture). When I look at the image URL as text, it becomes clear that the links are different and lead to different images (see picture). So I don't understand why the same image is displayed overall iterations although the url is different.

```
export class ImageUploadView extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangeImage = this.onChangeImage.bind(this);
    this.fileObj = [];
    this.fileArray = [];
}

onChangeImage (e) {
  this.fileObj.push(e.target.files)
        for (let i = 0; i < this.fileObj[0].length; i++) {
            this.fileArray.push(URL.createObjectURL(this.fileObj[0][i]))
        }
}

  render() {


    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <div className="card card-body mt-4 mb-4">


        <h1>Add Image</h1>

        <div>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.onChangeImage} multiple ref={this.inputRef} /> 

        {(this.fileArray || []).map((url) => (

            <MDBRow key={url} style={{ margin: '10px', display: 'inline-block' }}>
              <MDBCol>
                <MDBCard style={{ width: '5rem' }}>
                  <MDBCardImage className="img-fluid" src={url} waves />
                  <MDBCardBody>
                    <p> {url} </p>
                  </MDBCardBody>
                </MDBCard>
              </MDBCol>
            </MDBRow>
          
                    ))}
                
          </div> 


      </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Same picture different URL]

Comment: the problem might be hidden whithin `MBDCardImage`. can you post your code for that component here? Eventually you could set up a react stackblitz. would be easier to understand the issue

Comment: With React you're supposed to use `state` to store a component's data, like selected files. And your `onChangeImage` code looks quite fishy; `this.fileObj` is an empty array, and when the function is called, you're pushing the `FileList` from the input, meaning the array has now one element, which is a list of files.

Comment: Here's a fixed version: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-jackson-h6c4p?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for your answer! The code seems to wrok for single image preview but not for multiple images. For example when the user selects to two pictures, two pictures are provided as preview. I will contniue on the basis of your code. Thank you!

Comment: Okay i think i get it. When the user selects in a in single "selection session" ,  multiple pictures your code works and the preview of multiple pictures is possible. When the  user adds picture by picture in multiple "selection sessions" than not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, I've changed my code so selecting new files will append them instead.

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to add our code as answer.